# How can I overwrite @include in a css class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

My team's app is using bootstrap sass for some styling, but with certain customizations. The bootstrap files are added to our project via a build process, so I can't modify them directly.

For drop-down toggle elements, bootstrap is adding a small caret, which I'd like to remove. But it's done via an @include (shown below).

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  // Generate the caret automatically
  @include caret;
}
```

How would I overwrite this in our local sass files to remove/never display the caret?

EDIT: Here's a fix I ended up using. Not perfect, but it works.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Here's the caret mixin:

```
@mixin caret-down {
  border-top: $caret-width solid;
  border-right: $caret-width solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: $caret-width solid transparent;
}

@mixin caret-up {
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: $caret-width solid transparent;
  border-bottom: $caret-width solid;
  border-left: $caret-width solid transparent;
}

@mixin caret-right {
  border-top: $caret-width solid transparent;
  border-bottom: $caret-width solid transparent;
  border-left: $caret-width solid;
}

@mixin caret-left {
  border-top: $caret-width solid transparent;
  border-right: $caret-width solid;
  border-bottom: $caret-width solid transparent;
}

@mixin caret($direction: down) {
  @if $enable-caret {
    &::after {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      margin-left: $caret-width * .85;
      vertical-align: $caret-width * .85;
      content: "";
      @if $direction == down {
        @include caret-down;
      } @else if $direction == up {
        @include caret-up;
      } @else if $direction == right {
        @include caret-right;
      }
    }

    @if $direction == left {
      &::after {
        display: none;
      }

      &::before {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-right: $caret-width * .85;
        vertical-align: $caret-width * .85;
        content: "";
        @include caret-left;
      }
    }

    &:empty::after {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in which sass file is located dropdown-toggle ?

Comment: It's in scss/_dropdown.scss although I'm not sure if that's in the original bootstrap 4.0 package or a custom implementation of bootstrap from our UX group

Comment: I don't see any caret mixin in bootstrap... Please, share your full rendered css, not the scss...

Comment: The source is totally irrelevant. I just gave it for context. I have a file with styling that I can't directly change because it's added during the build. I need to overwrite this styling in another styling file.

If it were just straight css, I know I could just get the handle I need, add the new styling I need with !important. For @include (which as far as I know is scss syntax) I don't believe I can overwrite it that way.

Comment: I need the css of the mixin caret... Imagine it's in a before, or after pseudo-element, maybe you can just do display none...

Comment: I'll add the caret scss to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You can overide and remove the caret in using:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  &:after, &:before {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't exactly fix the issue, but I was able to derive a solution from it.

.dropdown-toggle::after {
 border: none !important;
}

Thanks for your help : )